# Mapping json response to custom object

Tags: ios, swift, swifty-json

I'm receiving following response from server.

```
 [
    {
      "resourceEmail" : "",
      "kind" : "admin#directory#resources#calendars#CalendarResource",
      "resourceId" : "",
      "resourceName" : "Inubation-Newton-4p",
      "resourceType" : "Confroom",
      "etags" : "\"eqO3c9wtJJ4wVWz2xe0E9HiU_D0\/rfmk2kZmhGi4HcHadds\""
    },
    {
      "resourceEmail" : "...",
      "kind" : "admin#directory#resources#calendars#CalendarResource",
      "resourceId" : "...",
      "resourceName" : "MVD11-R2-Napolitana",
      "resourceType" : "1 Tel Room",
      "etags" : "\"eqO3c9wtJJ4wVWz2xe0E9HiU_D0\/zcPwONBLID-O_3gvi0ly\""
    },
]
```

How can I transform above json array to array of custom object. I'm using SwiftyJSON for creating custom object. Below is my custom object class.

```
class CalendarResource: NSObject {
     var resourceID: String
     var resourceEmail: String
     var resourceName: String
     var etags: String

    init(json: JSON) {
        self.resourceID = json[Constants.Model.CalendarResource.resourceID].stringValue
        self.resourceEmail = json[Constants.Model.CalendarResource.resourceEmail].stringValue
        self.resourceName = json[Constants.Model.CalendarResource.resourceName].stringValue
        self.etags = json[Constants.Model.CalendarResource.etags].stringValue
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: you better create a model class and then append your objects in model class array.

Comment: You can also take a look at this library: 
https://github.com/hkellaway/Gloss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct CalendarResource {
     var resourceID: String
     var resourceEmail: String
     var resourceName: String
     var etags: String 

     init(json: JSON) {
    self.resourceID = json["resourceID"].stringValue
    self.resourceEmail = json["resourceEmail"].stringValue
    self.resourceName = json["resourceName"].stringValue
    self.etags = json["etags"].stringValue
    }
}
```

And when you are getting response for example like so:

```
//create array somewhere outside of the method, var calendarResourceArray: [CalendarResource]

let jsonArray = response    
self.calendarResourceArray = jsonArray!.map{CalendarResource(json: $0)}
```

Comment: Thanks! blinkmeoff. May be I've underestimated the power of map functions.. :)